# Docker for windows error: Cannot start service spark: container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a asp.net 4.6 web app that I am trying to test on docker for windows (10).

I am getting an error at the last step:

Cannot start service spark: container

```
========== Preparing Containers ==========
Getting Docker containers ready...
docker-compose  -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.override.yml" -p dockercompose4237870117037103515 --no-ansi config
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
services:
  spark:
    build:
      context: C:\git\spark\src\Spark
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: spark
    ports:
    - target: 80
version: '3.4'
docker-compose  -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.override.yml" -p dockercompose4237870117037103515 --no-ansi config
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
services:
  spark:
    build:
      context: C:\git\spark\src\Spark
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: spark
    ports:
    - target: 80
version: '3.4'
docker-compose  -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose4237870117037103515 --no-ansi config
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
services:
  spark:
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
      context: C:\git\spark\src\Spark
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe
      /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn
      /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"
    image: spark:dev
    ports:
    - target: 80
    volumes:
    - C:\git\spark\src\Spark:C:\inetpub\wwwroot:rw
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote
      Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
version: '3.4'
docker-compose  -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose4237870117037103515 --no-ansi build 
Building spark
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
 ---> f1ea9cd0268b
Step 2/4 : ARG source
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0b5901e69e59
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f4f8a96c5d93
Step 4/4 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1d140e25a4f5
Successfully built 1d140e25a4f5
Successfully tagged spark:dev
docker-compose  -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose4237870117037103515 --no-ansi config
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
services:
  spark:
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
      context: C:\git\spark\src\Spark
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe
      /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn
      /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"
    image: spark:dev
    ports:
    - target: 80
    volumes:
    - C:\git\spark\src\Spark:C:\inetpub\wwwroot:rw
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote
      Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
version: '3.4'
docker-compose  -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose4237870117037103515 --no-ansi config
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
services:
  spark:
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
      context: C:\git\spark\src\Spark
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe
      /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn
      /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"
    image: spark:dev
    ports:
    - target: 80
    volumes:
    - C:\git\spark\src\Spark:C:\inetpub\wwwroot:rw
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote
      Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
version: '3.4'
docker-compose  -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\git\spark\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose4237870117037103515 --no-ansi up -d --no-build --force-recreate --remove-orphans
A debug operation has started during container preparation, so the operation will be cancelled.
Recreating dockercompose4237870117037103515_spark_1 ... 
Recreating dockercompose4237870117037103515_spark_1 ... error
ERROR: for dockercompose4237870117037103515_spark_1  Cannot start service spark: container 642e2692725dc41d8683e96079a0ab12589dcc6523703e173f3ecc247002cff9 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present. (0x3ab9) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"642e2692725dc41d8683e96079a0ab12589dcc6523703e173f3ecc247002cff9","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\642e2692725dc41d8683e96079a0ab12589dcc6523703e173f3ecc247002cff9","Layers":[{"ID":"e4de2f6d-b210-5893-bb72-e2148f7f247b","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\d80690816c68740d0c7b268062d390bfdf13345e7dd4233dd7eadbaf57151c8b"},{"ID":"1f5bfd5c-f58c-53c6-b75d-ad1f45906e63","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\23202c07eac472f080d502e8b44f5eb0a4171fcfeee57cc9e2b850a54813670a"},{"ID":"26986c15-cc29-5090-972b-82684183a8e1","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\aeaa357c8fcf2ad4d230d48153fdb1a3f8c3218c21dea860df9de39cc7475712"},{"ID":"3379201d-e98b-584f-b6f5-26668d0e425f","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\1249f3a5c6d7dee77356bf1b62049bcd1b9469fa211aebd2e1e4a964088df247"},{"ID":"268cffdd-249f-59a7-b041-0951946dc18e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7ca1634792a5404ae801485e499e356f11eba41e158a8191a63fec2f4f38b756"},{"ID":"f7e20396-208d-546f-88d3-d821528d8274","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\6b9a15d0146feedbcebbff76e857295261f1de5da4120238d35a80a90051cbf8"},{"ID":"44b261c9-f2a2-52f4-8e3f-faa903d85bdf","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\498488b454599d10cdf62ecfe5108339ac85c9ac2e3f3e49a2bafe5532c496db"},{"ID":"49234037-d699-51ff-b7fb-a17483ae960d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\afbcd4621a32ab57bc79a510f50ddc116f9369b077a3e539e12342280ad34648"},{"ID":"f61c3cdb-d8ac-552f-aac5-c30374eb474a","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\2b726604a934d65967d29955a0b70e851876a9fa63dbacd0d3b9db80abb6291d"},{"ID":"4e736835-0260-5aa2-b0f3-b903c00e1d2d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\eb1bbf14d2a785269d72d3fec41930a0e04c555624d7f5fb16d44ce35b60e933"},{"ID":"1402eee0-9e76-5b39-ab9b-8e1108db3d0c","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\14309fdff18970c7da6749ba09e0706eddd71bd7be3f45615fb862a340fda4be"},{"ID":"27589929-16bc-5faf-a725-c77b3f05d982","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8649ccb5de012c3502e7e8292d8b1dd6bfaa19954d71a6389e3395c6d85adcb6"}],"HostName":"642e2692725d","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft visual studio\\2017\\professional\\common7\\ide\\remote debugger","ContainerPath":"c:\\remote_debugger","ReadOnly":true,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"c:\\git\\spark\\src\\spark","ContainerPath":"c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["09ed8063-5d3c-490d-bd67-f49730008220"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\14309fdff18970c7da6749ba09e0706eddd71bd7be3f45615fb862a340fda4be\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}
ERROR: for spark  Cannot start service spark: container 642e2692725dc41d8683e96079a0ab12589dcc6523703e173f3ecc247002cff9 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present. (0x3ab9) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"642e2692725dc41d8683e96079a0ab12589dcc6523703e173f3ecc247002cff9","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\642e2692725dc41d8683e96079a0ab12589dcc6523703e173f3ecc247002cff9","Layers":[{"ID":"e4de2f6d-b210-5893-bb72-e2148f7f247b","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\d80690816c68740d0c7b268062d390bfdf13345e7dd4233dd7eadbaf57151c8b"},{"ID":"1f5bfd5c-f58c-53c6-b75d-ad1f45906e63","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\23202c07eac472f080d502e8b44f5eb0a4171fcfeee57cc9e2b850a54813670a"},{"ID":"26986c15-cc29-5090-972b-82684183a8e1","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\aeaa357c8fcf2ad4d230d48153fdb1a3f8c3218c21dea860df9de39cc7475712"},{"ID":"3379201d-e98b-584f-b6f5-26668d0e425f","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\1249f3a5c6d7dee77356bf1b62049bcd1b9469fa211aebd2e1e4a964088df247"},{"ID":"268cffdd-249f-59a7-b041-0951946dc18e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7ca1634792a5404ae801485e499e356f11eba41e158a8191a63fec2f4f38b756"},{"ID":"f7e20396-208d-546f-88d3-d821528d8274","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\6b9a15d0146feedbcebbff76e857295261f1de5da4120238d35a80a90051cbf8"},{"ID":"44b261c9-f2a2-52f4-8e3f-faa903d85bdf","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\498488b454599d10cdf62ecfe5108339ac85c9ac2e3f3e49a2bafe5532c496db"},{"ID":"49234037-d699-51ff-b7fb-a17483ae960d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\afbcd4621a32ab57bc79a510f50ddc116f9369b077a3e539e12342280ad34648"},{"ID":"f61c3cdb-d8ac-552f-aac5-c30374eb474a","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\2b726604a934d65967d29955a0b70e851876a9fa63dbacd0d3b9db80abb6291d"},{"ID":"4e736835-0260-5aa2-b0f3-b903c00e1d2d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\eb1bbf14d2a785269d72d3fec41930a0e04c555624d7f5fb16d44ce35b60e933"},{"ID":"1402eee0-9e76-5b39-ab9b-8e1108db3d0c","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\14309fdff18970c7da6749ba09e0706eddd71bd7be3f45615fb862a340fda4be"},{"ID":"27589929-16bc-5faf-a725-c77b3f05d982","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8649ccb5de012c3502e7e8292d8b1dd6bfaa19954d71a6389e3395c6d85adcb6"}],"HostName":"642e2692725d","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft visual studio\\2017\\professional\\common7\\ide\\remote debugger","ContainerPath":"c:\\remote_debugger","ReadOnly":true,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"c:\\git\\spark\\src\\spark","ContainerPath":"c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["09ed8063-5d3c-490d-bd67-f49730008220"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\14309fdff18970c7da6749ba09e0706eddd71bd7be3f45615fb862a340fda4be\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

[image]

I am using visual studion 2018, latest release. See my version numbers for docker above.

Results from "docker images":

```
C:\Windows\System32>docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG                            IMAGE ID            CREATED SIZE
spark                   dev                            1d140e25a4f5        6 hours ago         5.33GB
spark                   latest                         674e73d5317f        24 hours ago        5.37GB
microsoft/aspnet        4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803   f1ea9cd0268b        2 days ago          5.33GB
microsoft/aspnet        latest                         f1ea9cd0268b        2 days ago          5.33GB
hello-world             latest                         739821c1f6d1        5 weeks ago         337MB
```

Running from command line appears to cause the same issue:

C:\git\spark\src\Spark>docker run -d spark

Thoughts?

Gina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the document that I was following specified that I don't need the -p argument. Which is not the case, probably because I have IIS running...

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 spark
```

Worked great. I was able to hit it using:

http://localhost:8070

Gina